# Change Icon of the Microsoft Excel on the Taskbar of the Windows 7 and earlier in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, windows-7, taskbar

I want to ***change the Icon of the Microsoft Excel*** application program on the ***task-bar of the Windows 7 and earlier***.

*I checked the Internet and only can find code lines for changing Icon of the Microsoft Excel Window. Those code change the task-bar Icon of the Microsoft Excel program in the Microsoft Windows Vista and XP.*

*I know that the logic of the Task-bar design has changed in Windows 7 and earlier Windows OSes; and I know that the Task-bar in mentioned Windows OSes uses 32 pixel Icons for displaying icon.*

So, I want to know how can I change the Icon of the Microsoft Excel on the Taskbar of the Windows 7+?

Answer (score 1):

Go to (*Depends where your Excel is installed, I'm using Excel 2007 on Windows 7*)

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12
```

Create a shortcut of Excel.exe on your desktop and right click on it and go to **properties**

Click on the **shortcut** tab and then from the bottom of the tab then click on **change icon** and confirm your choice of icon by clicking on OK.

Drag and drop your Excel Shortcut onto the task bar and *Da Da*, you get an Excel launcher with a new shortcut.

Comment: I would not recommend changing Excel.exe icon. It's against your license agreement.